# Iterate over slicer via VBA and select a single item each time

Tags: vba, excel

I have several slicers within a spreadhseet. I'd like to be able to loop over one of these via VBA, and select every option one by one. 
The macro below seems fine to my tired eyes, but it obviously doesn't work when I run it. When I add a breakpoint at the 'BREAKPOINT tag here below, the first item gets selected, but then the macro goes to the second one while keeping the first one selected and I end up with all my items selected...

```
    Sub slicers(slName As String)
    Dim slItem As SlicerItem, slDummy As SlicerItem
    Dim slBox As SlicerCache
    Set slBox = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(slName)
    For Each slItem In slBox .SlicerItems
      For Each slDummy In slBox .SlicerItems
          slDummy.Selected = (slDummy.Name = slItem.Name)
      Next slDummy
    Next slItem 'BREAKPOINT
    End Sub

    Sub test()
    Call slicers("A_slicer_name")
    End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

**EDIT:**
As pointed out by Scott Holtzman, turns out that I just need to clear the filter (slBox.ClearManualFilter) upon selecting a new item.

**Why is that necessary whereas the boolean test works properly when I debug.print it?**

The code below works fine:

```
    Sub slicers(slName As String)
    Dim slItem As SlicerItem, slDummy As SlicerItem
    Dim slBox As SlicerCache
    Set slBox = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(slName)
    For Each slItem In slBox .SlicerItems
      slBox.ClearManualFilter 'THIS IS THE LINE I NEEDED TO ADD
      For Each slDummy In slBox .SlicerItems
          slDummy.Selected = (slDummy.Name = slItem.Name)
      Next slDummy
    Next slItem
    End Sub

    Sub test()
    Call slicers("A_slicer_name")
    End Sub
```

Comment: I just answered a question just like this a few days back: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239727/loop-through-pivot-slicer-and-select-values/33241795#33241795). You need to basically show all results, and then in your double loop see if the `slItem` = `slDummy` and select if so, and turn off if not.

Comment: The code is ok, I actually just needed to clear the filter at the beginning of each loop. I don't get why though

Comment: you have to clear the filter so you essentially start over again ... because if you don't clear it, you have what you previously selected each time.

Comment: What I don't understand is that if I debug.print the boolean test within the inner loop, I'll get True/False/False/False, then False/True/False/False, then False/False/True/False and so on- which is what I would expect. So applying these booleans to the .Selected property of the slicer items should also switch them to the right state, without having to clear the filters. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the question I linked you too in my comment does not have an accepted answer (the user never choose to answer or reply to my suggestion), I will provide the solution to your problem here as well.

```
Sub slicers(slName As String)

    Dim slItem As SlicerItem, slDummy As SlicerItem
    Dim slBox As SlicerCache

    Set slBox = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(slName)

    'loop through each slicer item
    For Each slItem In slBox.SlicerItems

        'show all items to start
        slBox.ShowAllItems 'or .ClearManualFilter

        'test each item against itself
        For Each slDummy In slBox.SlicerItems

            'if the item equals the item in the first loop, then select it
            'otherwise don't show it (thus showing 1 at a time between the nested loops)
            If slItem.Name = slDummy.Name Then slDummy.Selected = True Else: slDummy.Selected = False

            'more code to process the data (I suspect)

        Next slDummy

    Next slItem

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.`slBox.ClearManualFilter` is what I needed to add.

Comment: `slBox.ShowAllItems` returns an error (could either be `slBox.ShowAllItems = False` or `slBox.ShowAllItems = True`) and does *not* fulfil the intended purpose to show all sliceritems. As already mentioned, `slBox.ClearManualFilter` or `slBox.ClearAllFilters` is necessary ***instead***.

Comment: Appreciated. A bit painful that it takes so long.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed have several selected items within an excel spreadsheet. The code you posted do nothing instead of selecting all items satisfying `slDummy.Name = slItem.Name`.

If I understand well, you want to run some code once the item is selected, and then go to the next item. You can achieve this by unselecting one item after use, with `item.selected = False`.

You may also want to select all items needed at first stage and then run a loop that will afect only the item that have the property `.selected` set to `true`. However it will probably be longer to execute as you'd have one more loop.

Comment: Please read again: it already has these two loops. There is no straightforward way to unselect all the items and thus you need an inner loop. The code you suggested won't work:
`Sub slicers(slName As String)
Dim slItem As SlicerItem
Dim slBox As SlicerCache
Set slBox = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(slName)
For Each slItem In slBox.SlicerItems
  slItem.Selected = False
Next slItem
For Each slItem In slBox.SlicerItems
  slItem.Selected = True
  slItem.Selected = False
Next slItem 

End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions but can't get them to work.
I kept getting a 1004 object not defined error; might be because I'm using the data model.
In the end I cobbled together this solution which picks up the slicer values from a range and then calls another macro to save in pdf (which was my ultimate objective).
Not elegant but effective.

```
Sub looop()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("B4:B5")
For Each cell In rng

ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_MasterBrand").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array("[Customer].[MasterBrand].&[" & cell.Value & "]")

a_ExportPDF

Next cell
    
End Sub
```