# Excel VBA: select all items from every slicer

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select all items from every slicer which exists in the workbook.

Currently I have the following, however this is producing a "Runtime error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method" on the 6th line where I start the loop through i:

```
Dim sc As SlicerCache
Dim sl As Slicer
Dim i As Integer
For Each sc In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
    For Each sl In sc.Slicers
        For i = 1 To sl.SlicerItems.Count
            sl.SlicerItems(i).Selected = True
        Next i
    Next sl
Next sc
```

I need the i loop in the middle because later on I want to use the same code to select only items which exist in an array.

Any help greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Maybe this post will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374563/iterate-over-slicer-via-vba-and-select-a-single-item-each-time

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change that line to `For i = 1 to sc.SlicerItems.Count` and it should work (slicerItems is a property of the SlicerCache and not the Slicer object itself

Comment: I believe you should also change the subsequent `sl` to `sc` in the loop