# How to deselect only one particular item in a slicer

Tags: excel, vba

I am finding it difficult to use VBA to deselect one particular item with a specific name from a slicer.

For context, in one workbook, I have a summary of revenue from all (23) products, and I have used VBA to successfully copy and paste data from a separate and more detailed workbook into this summary workbook. However, in my summary workbook, I want to know the total revenue from all products EXCEPT ONE (Product Name 2).
- How do I simply deselect this one item from a slicer in the detailed workbook, and then copy and paste the total-exception revenue data into my summary workbook?

When recording the macro (see below), I get the error, "Too many line continuations":

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_SLICERNAME"). _
        VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 3]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 4]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 5]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 6]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 7]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 8]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 9]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 10]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 11]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 12]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 13]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 14]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 15]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 16]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 17]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 18]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 19]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 20]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 21]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 22]", _
        "[Infor].[SLICER NAME].&[PRODUCT NAME 23]", _
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374563/iterate-over-slicer-via-vba-and-select-a-single-item-each-time

Comment: I tried applying the code from that thread into my workbook but I can't see how this is relevant for me. I come across multiple errors.
Please can you suggest any other potential solutions?

Comment: "I come across multiple errors" doesn't help us help you.  Typically the best way to get help here is (1) Show us exactly what you tried and (2) Explain *exactly* what went wrong when you ran your posted code.  It's difficult to formulate a useful response to "I tried a bunch of stuff and none of it worked" - all we're going to do is point you at already-posted examples (like I did above)

Comment: Sorry, I have now edited the post with some code I tried, which resulted in the error, "Too many line continuations". Hope this helps.
Thanks for your help with this.
Please let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**
Instead of trying to filter out the one particular product, I created a work-around. I filtered for only that product, copied the data onto the summary workbook, and then used a formula to subtract the singular product from the total values.
It takes the same amount of time to execute the whole vba. However, doesn't exactly look clean as there are way more lines than I originally wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Dim slc As SlicerCache

Set slc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Product")

slc.ClearManualFilter

slc.SlicerItems("Product 02").Selected = False
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I tried this and got:
"Run-time error '1004':
Application-define or object-define error."
When debugging it, the line highlighted is:
"slc.SlicerItems("Product 02").Selected = False"
Perhaps I have entered the name of the slicer cache incorrectly (second line)?
How do I find the name of the Slicer Cache for a particular slicer?

Comment: `For Each slc in ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches: Debug.Print slc.Name: Next`